# Is this cage too small?

Tags: containment, hamsters

[image]

Too small?

It has 2 sections, an upper level, and a second floor. It has 2 wooded houses, a stick of chewable things, and food stick, wooded logs, a second food bowl, a wheel, and only has tubes for traveling between sections.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. What type of animal and how many of them are you keeping in them? Please [edit] your question to provide more information.

Comment: Yes it is too small. And that there are smaller ones do not mean this one is okay. Unfortunately there are a lot of animal hurting things to buy in pet shops...

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:**

Yes, but it's better than others I have seen!

**Long Answer:**

Unfortunately pet shops have assured us that keeping hamsters in small cages is perfectly fine and that they like living in such conditions. This is simply not true.

For a Syrian hamster I would reccomend `1m x 50cm` of continous floor space. (Uninterrupted by pipes, extensions and the like.) This is possibly more generous than other suggestions online. However, this will also ensure that there's enough space for you to put some "fun" items into without crowding the box too much.
For a dwarf hamster `80cm x 40cm` should be suitable.

> **But my hamster cage has two floors... Doesn't this help with cage
>   size?**

It does, by all means don't take this answer as critisism it's simply reccomendations to ensure that both you and your hamster have the best experience. 
However, if you imagine your hamster in the wild what natural behaviour do you believe it would exhibit?

Answer: They are ground burrowers.

So in effect, you're better off giving them a large ground floor space with deep littering. But we will get onto that in a moment.

> **There are no sensibly priced hamster cages on the market with that amount of space.**

This is correct. Unfortunately the pet market makes so much money advertising these smaller cages in a variety of colours and with extra "add-ons". That nobody has stretched into creating bigger cages. However, don't let this put you off!

**A plastic storage container** from most homeware stores can double up as a large hamster cage. These tend to be either cheaper or competitively priced with store bought cages and you can have fun designing your own lid (with plenty of breathable holes!)

> **What does deep littering mean?**

Deep littering means having a thick base layer for your hamster. (it's also common in horse beds.)

I can see that you have a good amount of litter in your hamster cages and as a general rule of thumb I would put in 2-3 inches around the base and 4-5 possibly even 6 inches of bedding in a corner that you know they like to burrow or bed in.

> **I don't have the funds/I don't want to change out my current hamster set up.**

**I've just paid for this set up... I don't want to just get rid of it:** No problem, you can extend this set up into a storage box. Just measure up and cut out some holes in the storage box so you can connect the pipes (be careful it's not too big or your hamster will squeeze through the sides.)

**Lack of funds:** No issue your hamster should live in its current establishment fine. It may get a stressed or start showing unwanted behaviour after a while but it is "livable" so long as its basic needs are met. Make sure you take them out regularly in a hamster ball so they can burn off their energy and roam.

> **How many items are too many items?**

In your set up here there is no need for the two wooded houses they're just reducing the hamster's space. One should be just fine, after all your hamster can only use one at a time anyway. Pop one house out and keep it as a replacement for when your hamster chews the other.

Two food bowls aren't a neccessity either. I would pull one out and keep the other as your hamster's regular feeding station.

Your enrichments with chewable items and food sticks sound fine to me, just be sure that they aren't huge and that your hamster has enough space and you should be fine.

I hope this helps you on your journey through hamster ownership. Let me know if you have any other questions, if something I've said needs clarifying or I've missed anything.